# unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown 6

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

We keep running this error. The goal is to read the data from the array into an output file. Thanks for the help!

```
public static void save(Salesperson[] array)

  {
     PrintStream outfile = null;
     try
     {
        outfile = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("data.txt"));
     }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The file could not be created.");
        }
         System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt")));
     for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
     {
        System.out.println(array[k]);
     }

     outfile.close();
     System.out.println("Saved.");

  }
```

Comment: Okay, so what don't you understand about it? It seems fairly clear to me. How much do you understand about checked exceptions? And do you *really* need to redirect `System.out`? (Why not just write to the file, without the redirection?)

Comment: Read the [Java tutorial about exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/), or your Java introductory book.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because there is a [checked exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129) associated with [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29) which you are not catching/`throw`-declaring.

Comment: Specifically which exception? I understand the problem now but I'm not sure which exception it's missing...

Comment: You are not handling `FileNotFoundException` for your second `new FileOutputStream()`.

Comment: @user2373182: the exception message says: unreported exception **java.io.FileNotFoundException**; must be caught or declared to be thrown. Read the exception message.